# login website using casperjs?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am try to login a site using casperjs .

I try this code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/45.0.2 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36'
    }
});

casper.start().thenOpen("https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html", function() {
    console.log("amazon site  website opened");
    var html = this.getPageContent();
    console.log(html);
});
casper.then(function(){
    console.log("Login using username and password");
    this.evaluate(function(){
        document.getElementById("username").value="******";
        document.getElementById("password").value="******";
        document.getElementById("sign-in-button").click();
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
console.log("Make a screenshot and save it as AfterLogin.png");
    this.wait(40000);
    this.capture('AfterLogin.png');
});
casper.run();
```

But I get the output

```
 <html><head></head><body></body></html>  
   Login using username and password
   Make a screenshot and save it as AfterLogin.png
   []
```

when I print console.log(html) that only print above html tags.
I also try same code for facebook.com still get same .

Comment: There were problems with older phantomjs version where you could not connect without setting specific ssl-protocol parameter. Try passing parameter ```--ssl-protocol=tlsv1```

Comment: I try this but now My program is not printing any thing and not exit too

Comment: what casperjs and phantomjs version are you using ?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Are you sure this is phantomjs version, if so its quite old build its now 2.x. ```casperjs --version```

Comment: sory  phantomjs  version is 1.9.7  and casperjs version 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use nightmare.js or phantom.js. Both will allow i to read html from website and simulate events.

Alternatively, u can check the endpoints and just hit them there to retrieve data

Comment: any reference where I can get example.

Comment: Well casperjs is already using phantomjs, but with additional helper methods to make the navigation etc easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be binded to unsuccessful CAPTCHA test pass (you'll miss it when using `loadImages: false`) at `//*[@id="ap_captcha_img"]/img` XPath on given response.

In a CasperJS/1.1.1+PhantomJS/2.1.1 setup, using a similar code

```
var sURL = 'https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html';
var casper = require("casper").create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: true,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/45.0.2 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36'
    }
});

casper.start();
casper.thenOpen(sURL, function() {
    console.log("website opened");
    var html = this.getPageContent();
    console.log(html);
});
casper.then(function(){
    console.log("Login using username and password");
    this.fill('form[name=signinWidget]', {
            'username': 'username',
            'password': '123456'
        }, true);
});
casper.wait(10000, function() {
    console.log("Make a screenshot and save it as AfterLogin.png");
    this.capture('AfterLogin.png');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

got the following output

```
website opened
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

<!--
whole resource HTML
-->

</body></html>
Login using username and password
Make a screenshot and save it as AfterLogin.png
```

[image]